# Deleting row from database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've created a database table called "users" and filled it with some data.
I want to delete a row in PHP, because I am creating a website with accounts. So if a user wants to delete his account he has to enter his username and hit the "delete" button. I have written this PHP code but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Any help about fixing the issue please?

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
```

$_POST[form_username] ;

```
//connection_start
$mysqli = new mysqli('mysql3.000webhost.com','a4305565_os','******','a4305565_users');

//check_connection
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die("Connection error (check_connection): " . $mysqli->connect_errno . " : " . $mysqli->connect_error );
    exit();
}

//delete_data
$deleteUser = "DELETE * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = "$_POST[form_username]" LIMIT 1" ;
$delete = $mysqli->query($deleteUser);

//verification
if($delete){
    printf ("Account id %d.\n has been deleted.", $mysqli->insert_id);
}else{
    die("Error (verification): {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}

//Connection_end
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: DELETE does not require *. Just `DELETE FROM ...`

Comment: Two advices: use something like phpMyAdmin to check your queries, so that you can know it is not a PHP error but a SQL error. And second: when creating a web page, learn a framework and use it. You'll not regret it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your string.

```
$deleteUser = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = '".$_POST[form_username]."' LIMIT 1" ;
```

You need single quotes around the strings you are inputing and dots inside to tell PHP you are using variables. You should however escape your data so you aren't vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Try using

```
$username = $mysql->escape_string($_POST['username']);
$deleteUser = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = '".$username."' LIMIT 1" ;
```

Comment: this is giving me error on the line where `$username = $mysql->escape_string($_POST['username']);` is in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
"DELETE  FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = '".$_POST['form_username']."' LIMIT 1" ;
```

above is the proper way to write query and 
from where u r getting the `$_POST['form_username']` value

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
$deleteUser = "DELETE * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = "$_POST[form_username]" LIMIT 1" ;
```

To

```
$deleteUser = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = "$_POST[form_username]" LIMIT 1" ;
```